# How to delete columns from df that are "character", change "logical" columns to numeric (are 1s and 0s), run cor despite blank cells, "N/A" in cells

Tags: r, correlation

The links provided do not solve the issue. Here is my edited problem:

There are hundreds of columns and I need to run `cor` for several.

**1)** I have to delete "character" columns from my df before running cor.

**2)** I also have to convert "logical" columns to "numeric". These "logical" columns are already in format of 1 or 0.

**3)** In each row are additional potential issues: (A) blank cells, (B) cells that say "N/A"

**4)** Basically, looking to run cor and trying to remove obstacles in way of doing that.

```
sapply(dfcor,class)
cor(dfcor, use = "complete.obs")
```

**Error message:**

> Error in cor(dfcor, use = "complete.obs") : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: You can also try: `purrr::discard(dfcor,is.character)`.

Comment: Ray, generally it is a good idea to make a simple example that illustrates the full problem you are facing; some guidance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250 Also, it is sometimes useful to isolate one problem at a time (eg, I don't think R has such a thing as blank values, so might want to fix that first?).

Comment: Your description of the problem is not adequate without code to reproduce the issue, since "blanks" is unclear; logical columns (in R lingo) cannot have "N/A" so that term is also ambiguous here; and so on. This is typical for R questions - it is necessary to provide code others can copy-paste to see the issue. As noted in the link, "This does take some work but seems like a fair trade-off since you are asking others to do work for you." `cor` runs just fine on what R calls logical columns, btw. Try `cor(data.frame(a = c(T,F,T), b = c(F,F,T)))`

Comment: @Frank though correlations on binary variables ? Probably not the best idea...

Answer (score 1):

We create a logical vector by checking whether the class is `character`, remove those columns by negating (`!`) and get the `cor` on those subset of columns

```
i1 <- sapply(dfcor, is.character)
cor(dfcor[!i1], use = "complete.obs")
```

---

The main issue regarding the post is why the error occurred.  It is due to the fact that `?cor` expects a numeric column/matrix/data.frame according to `?cor`

> x - a numeric vector, matrix or data frame.